# GLSL soft planar shadows: matrix transformation

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, shadow, affinetransform

I'm adding some modest features to an [older video game engine](http://github.com/jdolan/quake2world). It has simple planar shadows, using the stencil buffer and a [projection matrix popularized in SGI's cookbook](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/blythe/advanced99/notes/node192.html) years ago.

[image: Not half bad looking]
[image: But if the shadow could fade out with the light's radius..]

These work reasonably well, except they do not fade in intensity according to the attenuation of the light source. That's what I'd like to accomplish in my shader. Unfortunately, I can't figure out the correct transformation to allow this. Here's my shader source code. I'm stuck with `#version 120`.

**EDIT: This is now the updated shader which works**

```c
/*
 * @brief Planar shadows vertex shader.
 */

#version 120

uniform mat4 MATRIX;

varying vec4 point;

/*
 * @brief
 */
void ShadowVertex() {

    point = gl_ModelViewMatrix * MATRIX * gl_Vertex;    
}

/*
 * @brief Program entry point.
 */
void main(void) {

    // mvp transform into clip space
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * MATRIX * gl_Vertex;

    // and primary color
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;

    ShadowVertex();
}
```

```cs
/*
 * @brief Planar shadows fragment shader.
 */

#version 120

uniform vec4 LIGHT;

varying vec4 point;

/*
 * @brief
 */
void ShadowFragment(void) {

    float dist = distance(LIGHT.xyz, point.xyz / point.w);

    float intensity = (LIGHT.w - dist) / LIGHT.w;

    if (intensity <= 0.0)
        discard;

    gl_FragColor.a = min(gl_Color.a, intensity);
}

/*
 * @brief Program entry point.
 */
void main(void) {

    gl_FragColor = gl_Color;

    ShadowFragment();
}
```

`MATRIX` is the projection matrix from the planar shadow tutorial. The shape of the shadow is correct, so I don't believe there's any problem there. I understand that this is not an affine transformation, but I'm unclear on the implications.

`LIGHT.xyz` is the light source's coordinates in eye space. `LIGHT.w` is the light's radius (attenuation). What I'm confused on is how to get a meaningful comparison from `light` to `point` in the fragment shader -- or really, why what I'm trying there is wrong. I end up with no shadows at all; in other words, the calculated `intensity` value is always `<= 0.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpful community members of ##OpenGL on Freenode pointed out my error. As the projection matrix `MATRIX` does not produce an affine transformation, I needed to divide the distance calculation by `point.w`. This yields the correct distance between `LIGHT.xyz` and `point.xyz`.

In short, if you're working with a projection matrix like this, be sure you understand how to deal with all 4 coordinate components, or know who to ask :)